# Fill Null Values with Last Previous Value and add 1 as a continuous integer for every value going forward - Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null

I have these two columns in Big Query: budget_id and activity:

| budget_id | activity | region | execution window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000507_Corporate | 507 | Corporate | 2022 |
| 000508_AMERICAS | 508 | AMERICAS | 2022Q2 |
| NULL | NULL | c | b |
| NULL | NULL | c | b |

The budget_id comes from a Google Sheet which is manually inputted by a stakeholder. I'm trying to change this that going forward, I can automate this myself. Everything from 000001 to 000508 mostly comes from a spreadsheet. I'm trying to automated this going forward. However, this has been trickier than I thought.

```sql
WITH blah AS (
select *,
IF(activity IS NULL, last_value(activity ignore nulls) over (order by activity RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) + 1, activity) AS new_activity
from `rax-datamart-dev.marketing.auto_budget_framework`)
select budget_id,
activity, 
region,
execution_window,
new_activity
from blah
order by activity NULLS last
```

| budget_id | activity | region | execution window | new_activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000507_Corporate | 507 | Corporate | 2022 | 507 |
| 000508_AMERICAS | 508 | AMERICAS | 2022Q2 | 508 |
| NULL | NULL | c | b | 509 |
| NULL | NULL | c | b | 509 |

As you can see, I'm able to get 509 so that's promising. Unfortunately, I was hoping the next NULL value row would be 510. And then if there is another NULL value, 511, 512, 513 etc etc.

Is what I'm attempting even possible? I feel like I'm missing something but if anyone could help out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to replace at least one of your table screenshots, a per current Stack Overflow rules you were downvoted for that reason. Reference on how to do it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

Comment: Yes, it definitely helped. I can see the increment working on my end. Also, I like the little trick with just adding the number and new_activity column. I didn't think about that at the time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using similar data as you posted in your question.

```
with data as (
 SELECT 'Americas_1 '  as id,1 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT 'Americas_2 '  as id,2 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT 'Americas_3 '  as id,3 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT 'Americas_4 '  as id,4 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT null  as id,null as activity, 'c' as region union all
 SELECT null  as id,null as activity, 'a' as region
)
```

In the subquery `data`, I just have the sample data. In the second subquery `data2`, I added a `column number`, this column adds the `row_number` when the `activity column` is null, if it is not null add a 0. The `column new_activity` just puts the same numbers when activity is not null.

Here you can see the complete query.

```
with data as (
 SELECT 'Americas_1 '  as id,1 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT 'Americas_2 '  as id,2 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT 'Americas_3 '  as id,3 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT 'Americas_4 '  as id,4 as activity, 'America' as region union all
 SELECT null  as id,null as activity, 'c' as region union all
 SELECT null  as id,null as activity, 'a' as region
), data2 as (
 
select id,activity, region, 
IF (activity is null,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY activity),0) as number,
IF(activity IS NULL,
last_value(activity ignore nulls) over (order by activity RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ,
activity ) as new_activity
from data
group by id,activity, region
order by activity asc nulls last
)
```

This query displays these `columns ID, activity, region`; and in the last column `new_Activity`, I sum the column `number` and `new_activity` from the subquery data2

```
select id, activity, region, (number+new_activity) as new_Activity from data2
order by activity asc nulls last
```

This is the output of the query.

[image]